# How to plot positive and negative values on both sides of the axis in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

Could anyone please tell me how is it possible to plot a graph in Excel or LibreOffice in which different values for a single variable can be plotted on both sides of X-axis but in a way that both positive and negative values remain anti-parallel to each other.

```
Chromosome  Antisense   Sense
Chr1        4.33E+011   -3.09E+011
Chr2        2.33E+011   -4.09E+011
Chr3        4.33E+011   -3.09E+011
Chr4        2.33E+011   -4.09E+011
```

Answer (score 3):

From my understanding of your question, you want to draw a line chart with two lines (sense and antisense) separated by the 0 axis and each line contains data points for each Chromosome. Just like the chart shows below?

[image]

Please comment me if this chart is right. I made this chart using an Excel add-in called Funfun, it allows me to use JavaScript directly in Excel so I could use Chart.js library to plot this chart from the data in the spreadsheet. You could check the code on the link below.

https://www.funfun.io/1/edit/5a2d3865cdeaed4cdfca615f

You could also connect the link above to your excel so all the codes and chart will be directly loaded into your Excel. Here are some screenshots of what it looks like.

[image]

[image]

***Disclosure: I'm a developer of Funfun***

Answer (score 1):

Try plotting the bar chart in this way, where by you will be able to see the positive and negative values for one object.

Select the cells of value that you would like to plot the chart > Insert tab > select the chart type > and choose other options like given in the below screenshot. So that it classifies the two values for single object.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: The OP specified Excel 2007 and your answer is Excel 2013, so your screen shot info isn't accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? If so, please comment and I can add more detail about how to do it.

[image: antiparallel]

Answer (score 0):

This is with Excel 2010 but the Menu is almost the same (also in 2013 -.-)
My [Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up1AT.jpg) is in Spanish but they are at the same position. 
You can use stacked or with de original values.