# Excel Charting - How to edit the X axes for positive value on both sides?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I have a stacked chart, with the X axes at bottom. So there are two bars protruding along the y axes from each category. to get an idea of the X axes, it's something like this

[How to plot positive and negative values on both sides of the axis in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/847973/how-to-plot-positive-and-negative-values-on-both-sides-of-the-axis-in-excel) (second answer)

So, by default the X axes moving towards left side would have negative values but I want that to be positive too. Essentially I am trying to compare two different columns horizontally.

Comment: Is this what you would like your Chart to look like? ![Stacked Bar Chart with positive values at both ends of the X axis.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uid7D.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a screen shot (or put one on a hosting site and link it), of what your final product should look like?

Comment: Short answer, anything you want to show to the left of the axis you have to change to a negative value (even if it is positive), then use custom number formatting in the axis to show positive instead of negative left of the 0 value of the axis.

Comment: yeah, I was able to do that but since my values are in percentages I am having trouble converting it to percentage. But I did find the solution to it. Instead of using 0;0 which gave +ive no. on both sides I was using 0;0% which gave +ive %age on just one side. Then it struck me that it needs to be 0%;0%.Thank you so much.

Comment: You should post your answer as the answer and mark it as accepted.  That way you can help others with the same problem and get credit for figuring it out!